# phpmyadmin The "templates/" directory does not exist

Tags: phpmyadmin, apache2.4

Installed phpMyAdmin by unzipping the download to the apache 2.4 htdocs. Granted authority to the server user. 
Added a config.inc.php file with the config of a MySql/Mariadb server.
When trying to access the phpMyAdmin main page from a browser, I'm getting a '500 internal server error'. The apache log is telling me a templates directory is missing. When checking the tree, its there.
Any idea's?

Comment: What user owns the templates directory and what are the permissions? Is that your webserver user? Are there any files in it, and if so, check the owner/permissions of those as well. Which operating system and version are you using? The templates directory (and a whole bunch of files/subdirectories under it) should come with the standard installation and *should* be uncompressed just like all the other directories and files in the phpMyAdmin folder with matching permissions and ownership, so this seems a bit odd to me.

Comment: @isaac. we have already open-up the access for everyone on the installation (777). This without any success. We are running apache2.4 on I5/OS. Other soft like adminer runs ok.

Comment: Can you look at https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/16184 and see if the patch there helps you?

Answer (score 0):

Apply [ddb66ad61a86f1afa491fc326213476a4607791c](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/commit/ddb66ad61a86f1afa491fc326213476a4607791c) or [cae9e527fbaf74a93101f27e72b740406507ebf6](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/commit/cae9e527fbaf74a93101f27e72b740406507ebf6) for a more targeted fix

Ref: my comment on [#16184](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/16184#issuecomment-642859448)

For the visitors of the future, any version superior or equal to 5.0.3 (not released at the time I write this reply) will contain this fix.